# How to select multiple rows in one column with a given condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

### Employee Table

```
Id      Name
-------------
1        Joy
2       Moni
3       Evan
4      farhad
```

### Absent table

```
Date(y/m/d)   Id
-----------------
2015/1/1      1
2015/1/3      1
2015/1/4      1
2015/1/5      1
2015/1/1      2
2015/1/4      2
2015/1/5      2
2015/1/5      3
```

I have need data from above two tables as like as bellow

```
Name              Date
Joy     2015/1/5, 2015/1/4, 2015/1/3    
Moni    2015/1/5, 2015/1/4
Evan    2015/1/5
```

Point 1: I will not take date `2015/1/1` because date `2015/1/2` is missing for employee id  '1' For Joy in Date Table
Point 2: I will not take date '2015/1/1' because date '2015/1/3' and '2015/1/2' is missing for employee id '2' for moni in date Table

I have tried the problem like this bellow, this worked fine for my problem but its take two much execution time for big data. How can i do that another way so that i will get minimum execution time.

### CODE

```
select a.Id,a.name , [dbo].[hello] ('2015/1/1','2015/1/5',a.Id)  From
Employee a

    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[hello](@start datetime,@End datetime,@Id int)
    returns varchar(1111)
AS

begin
declare
        @TempDate  DateTime,
        @CombainedDate  varchar(1111)= '',


        while(@End>=@start)

        begin


          select @ TempDate  = (select distinct Date from Absent  d where Date=@End and EmployeeId=@Id)

           if
            @ TempDate  = @End
            begin
           set @End = DATEADD(day, -1, @End)
           set @ CombainedDate  +=  ',' + cast(@TempDate  as varchar(1111)) 
          end
            else
            begin
            break
            end
           end
       return @ CombainedDate  
        end
```

Comment: Do you have non clustered index for table Absent which includes Date and EmployeeId fields ? If not , it can increase this query performance.

Comment: What will be result for Moni if the data is `2015/1/1      2
2015/1/4      2
2015/1/5      2
2015/1/8      2
2015/1/9      2`?

Comment: Thanks,  [2015/1/9,2015/1/8 if enddate=2015/1/9] [2015/1/5,2015/1/4 if enddate=2015/1/5] @ Giorgi Nakeuri –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code(Modifying Modifying Giorgi Nakeuri's solution)

```
DECLARE @sd DATETIME,
    @ed DATETIME 
SET @sd = '20150101' 
SET @ed = '20150106'

DECLARE @e TABLE
(
  ID INT ,
  Name NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT  INTO @e
  SELECT  1, 'Joy' 
UNION 
SELECT  2, 'Moni' 
UNION 
SELECT  3, 'Evan'
UNION 
SELECT 4, 'Farhad'




DECLARE @a TABLE ( ID INT, d DATETIME )

INSERT  INTO @a (ID, D)
        SELECT  1, '20150101'
        union
        SELECT  1, '20150103'
        union
        SELECT  1, '20150104'
        union
        SELECT  1, '20150105'
        union
        SELECT  2, '20150101'
        union
        SELECT  2, '20150104'
        union
        SELECT  2, '20150105'
        union
        SELECT  3, '20150105';

   DECLARE @T TABLE ( ID INT, d DATETIME )
   INSERT INTO @T(ID,d)
   SELECT X.ID, X.D FROM
  (SELECT ID,d FROM @a
   WHERE d BETWEEN @sd AND @ed) X
 INNER JOIN
(SELECT ID, d FROM @a
WHERE d = @ed) Y  ON X.ID=Y.ID;


WITH    cte
      AS ( SELECT   ID ,
                    sd = MIN(d) ,
                    ed = MAX(d) ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY MAX(d)
                                        - MIN(d) DESC, MAX(d) DESC ) AS rn
           FROM     ( SELECT    ID ,
                                CAST(d AS INT) AS d ,
                                rn = CAST(d AS INT)
                                - ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY d )
                      FROM      @T
                      WHERE     d >= @sd
                                AND d <= @ed
                    ) a
           GROUP BY ID ,
                    rn
         )
SELECT  e.Name ,
        ( SELECT    STUFF((SELECT   ',' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), d, 112)
                           FROM     @T a WHERE a.ID = c.ID AND a.d >= c.sd AND a.d <= c.ed
                           ORDER BY d desc
                    FOR   XML PATH('') ,
                              TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
        ) AS Date
FROM    cte c
        JOIN @e e ON e.ID = c.ID
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is demo. It uses some island solution and then XML query technique for concatenating rows to one string:

```
DECLARE @sd DATE = '20150101' , @ed DATE = '20150105'

DECLARE @e TABLE
    (
      ID INT ,
      Name NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )
DECLARE @a TABLE ( ID INT, d DATETIME )

INSERT  INTO @e
VALUES  ( 1, 'Joy' ),
        ( 2, 'Moni' ),
        ( 3, 'Evan' ),
        ( 4, 'Farhad' )


INSERT  INTO @a
VALUES  ( 1, '20150101' ),
        ( 1, '20150103' ),
        ( 1, '20150104' ),
        ( 1, '20150105' ),
        ( 2, '20150101' ),
        ( 2, '20150104' ),
        ( 2, '20150105' ),
        ( 3, '20150105' );

WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   ID ,
                        sd = MIN(d) ,
                        ed = MAX(d) ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY MAX(d)
                                            - MIN(d) DESC, MAX(d) DESC ) AS rn
               FROM     ( SELECT    ID ,
                                    CAST(d AS INT) AS d ,
                                    rn = CAST(d AS INT)
                                    - ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY d )
                          FROM      @a
                          WHERE     d >= @sd
                                    AND d <= @ed
                        ) a
               GROUP BY ID ,
                        rn
             )
    SELECT  e.Name ,
            ( SELECT    STUFF((SELECT   ',' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), d, 112)
                               FROM     @a a WHERE a.ID = c.ID AND a.d >= c.sd AND a.d <= c.ed
                               ORDER BY d desc
                        FOR   XML PATH('') ,
                                  TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
            ) AS Date
    FROM    cte c
            JOIN @e e ON e.ID = c.ID
    WHERE   rn = 1
```

Output:

```
Name    Date
Joy     20150105,20150104,20150103
Moni    20150105,20150104
Evan    20150105
```

Comment: If the @ed do not match in Absent Table Then i want to break here. suppose in your solution @ed='20150106' then your output will be same.

Comment: if @ed  do not match in absent table i will show null for particular employee. if @ed=20150205 then output will  Joy                                          20150105,20150104,20150103
Moni                                       20150105,20150104
Evan                                          20150105                                          where your solution is correct.         But if @ed=20150106 in this case i will not show anything for employee there is no date like '20150106' in absent table.

Comment: @JoyAcharya, can't edit my answer now. Look at this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f4dae/9
Pay attention on cross apply.

Comment: Thanks, i have already solved the problem by modifying your code. The solution is bellow.

Answer (score 1):

Your function [hello] query database a few times per one execution. My proposal is to eliminate it.
Create temporary table for storing dates between start date and end date. And then use loop or cursor(or something else) to calculate string with all dates you need.
As result you will query your database once inside function hello and increase performance

Comment: Thanks,Now i have not right to create temporary table in my project. I will do it next.without temporary table is there any way?

Comment: @Joy Acharya . It is very strange ... I mean not temporary table in database, but temporary table variables. Example here [http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/2910/temporary-tables-and-table-variables/]. Please double check